# Is it possible to access a property from the control's view model from a listview item template?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I am creating a feature where as you navigate through menu items you are given breadcrumbs to go back.  In order to create this in my Windows 8 app, I am generating a collection of items and adding on to that collection as I navigate through the menu.

The xaml code for displaying the breadcrumbs is:

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Top"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="120,60,0,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text=">>" />
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

While this works, I am not 100% happy with the bindings of the button.  The problem is I am invoking functionality that is already up and running on my overall control's view model, and this seems to require me to have an `OpenCommand` property on my inner item command.

Is it possible to bind my button's `Command=` attribute to a command on the control's overall view model, instead of the list item itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible by something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text=">>" />
                <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenCommand, ElementName=listView}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    ...
</ListView>
```